# Passing multiple id's from checkboxes to my controller in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, laravel-5, bootstrap-table

in my view page i have a list of checkbox item in a table format. I want to send id of the selected checkbox(could be multiple id) when user click the add button to my controller. In the controller i will fetch some value and will pass it on to another view. 
below is my code

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="contact_form_holder">
                    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'booking','METHOD' => 'POST')) }}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        {{form::text('checkin','',['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Check In Date','id'=>'checkin'])}}
                        <div id="error_datepicker" class="error">Please check again</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        {{form::text('checkout','',['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Check Out Date','id'=>'checkout'])}}
                        <div id="error_datepicker" class="error">Please check again</div>
                    </div>
                    <p id="btnsubmit">
                        <input type="submit" id="send" value="Search" class="btn btn-custom"/>
                    </p>
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @if (isset($roomname))
                    <table class="table table-hover" data-toggle="table" id="table"
                           data-click-to-select="true">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>

                            <th data-field="roomname">Room Name</th>
                            <th data-field="Desc">Description</th>
                            <th data-field="price">Price</th>
                            <th data-field="roomid" data-visible="false">Price</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($roomname as $value)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $value->roomname !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $value->Desc !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $value->price !!}</td>
                            <td>{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br>

                    <button id="add_cart" class="btn btn-warning">Proceed to booking</a></button>
                    <!-- on click of this button i want the clicked item id from the table and send it to the controller and from the controller it shoud redirect the value to another page  -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

my javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/roombooking',
    type: "get",
    data: {id: data},
    success: function (response) { // What to do if we succeed
        if (data == "success") {
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error' + response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tell us what you tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap your table inside form tag, and then use jquery serialize() method to get the all content for ex.

```
   @if (isset($roomname))
          <form id="testForm">
                <table class="table table-hover" data-toggle="table" id="table"
                       data-click-to-select="true">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>

                        <th data-field="roomname">Room Name</th>
                        <th data-field="Desc">Description</th>
                        <th data-field="price">Price</th>
                        <th data-field="roomid" data-visible="false">Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($roomname as $value)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $value->roomname !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $value->Desc !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $value->price !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $value->roomid !!}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </form>
                @endif
```

then in javascript use below

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/roombooking',
    type: "get",
    data: $('#testForm').serialize(),
    success: function (response) { // What to do if we succeed
        if (data == "success") {
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert('Error' + response);
    }
});
```

make sure you checkboxes are array in html
so in all checkbox name attribute should be something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" />
```

then in your laravel controller you will get Request::all() will have 'selected' array

Comment: how to access name selected[] in the controller

Comment: use Request::input('selected') will return the array of selected ids

Answer (score 1):

For passing multiple id's from check boxes, you can do it by the help of arrays.
Suppose (just for example) if there are 4 check-boxes on a page enclosed inside a form tag, you can implement the way - code below:

```
<form action="some_url" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="1"> My Value 1
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="2"> My Value 2
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="3"> My Value 3
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="4"> My Value 4
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So if you submit this form by checking all the check-boxes the output of posted data will be like:

```
<?php

    $inputs = request()->all();
    /*

     Inputs will have -
     $inputs = array(
        'ids' => array(1, 2, 3, 4);
     );

    */

?>
```

So you'll receive ids using [request()->all()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request) method of Laravel.
Hope this will help you to solve your problem...!!